# How to use AnimatedSwitcher and CustomScrollView together

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I want switch status with animation in `CustomScrollView`, but it throw error.

```dart
class SliverAnimatedSwitcher extends StatefulWidget {
  final state;

  const SliverAnimatedSwitcher({Key key, this.state}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SliverAnimatedSwitcherState createState() => _SliverAnimatedSwitcherState();
}

class _SliverAnimatedSwitcherState extends State<SliverAnimatedSwitcher> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('SliverAnimatedSwitcher'),
          ),
          _buildContent(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  get state => widget.state;

  Widget _buildContent() {
    var content;
    if (state.isNotEmpty == true) {
      content = SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context, index) {
            var item = state.items[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.title),
            );
          },
          childCount: state.items.length,
        ),
      );
    } else if (state.isError) {
      content = SliverFillRemaining(
        key: Key('error'),
        child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Error')),
      );
    } else if (state.isLoading) {
      content = SliverFillRemaining(
        key: Key('loading'),
        child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Loading')),
      );
    } else {
      content = SliverFillRemaining(
        key: Key('empty'),
        child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Empty')),
      );
    }
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      child: content,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) package on pub.dev that has a [SliverAnimatedSwitcher](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools#sliveranimatedswitcher). You'd use it like this:

```
SliverAnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
  child: content,
)
```

Comment: It would be best, if there is a ready full example how to use it

Comment: Well, `SliverAnimatedSwitcher` does not support `transitionBuilder` yet. So the feature doesn't support using custom transitions. The animation for now only supports fade transition.

Answer (score 3):

It is because sliver widget is not capable with `Stack` which is using as layout builder inside `AnimatedSwitcher`.

I found a temporary solution. Though the result is not equal to the original one (only show the last widget in the result), but I think it is acceptable for me now with such little effort.

1. First create a `SliverAnimatedSwitcher` exact the same code as `AnimatedSwitcher` [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_switcher.dart)
2. Modify the `Stack` part to return the `currentChild` only (defaultLayoutBuilder)
3. Change `FadeTransition` to `SliverFadeTransition` (defaultTransitionBuilder)

.

```
static Widget defaultLayoutBuilder(Widget currentChild, List<Widget> previousChildren) {
  return currentChild;
}
```

.

```
static Widget defaultTransitionBuilder(Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
  return SliverFadeTransition(
    opacity: animation,
    sliver: child,
  );
}
```

If someone can find a way to Stack Sliver widgets above each other, the result may be more perfect.